# How to get child element in ExtJS 4

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4

How to get all the child elements or id of a Panel in ExtJS 4?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I wrote that function for you. I think it will help you.

`function getAllChildren (panel) {
  /*Get children of passed panel or an empty array if it doesn't have thems.*/
  var children = panel.items ? panel.items.items : [];
  /*For each child get their children and concatenate to result.*/
  Ext.each(children, function (child) {
    children = children.concat(getAllChildren(child));
  })
  return children;
}`

It takes panel (container) as a parameter and returns all children and subchildren recursively.

**EDIT**
This will return ids of children. **USES PREVIOUS FUNCTION - getAllChilden**

```
function getAllChildenIds(panel) {
  //*Get all child items. \*/
 var children = getAllChilden(panel);
 //*Replace items with their ids.\*/
 for (var i=0, l=children.length; i < l; i++) {
   children[i] = children[i].getId();
 }
 return children;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Zango, your code is working fine but i want id of each child element of panel. but facing problem in that.

Answer (score 10):

Just call query() on your panel which will return an array of all child elements which match an optional selector.
 i.e. panel.query()